# Angucomplete-alt: Remote-API-handler not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete

I'm using angucomplete-alt (https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) in an AngularJS project, however I can't seem to make it work.

I'm trying to build a really simple autocomplete form, like this:

```
<angucomplete-alt pause="400" selected-object="obj" remote-api-handler="search" title-field="id" minlength="1" />
```

And my function is defined in the controller as such:

```
    $scope.search= function (userInputString, timeoutPromise) {
    return $timeout(function () {
        return [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }, { "id": "3" }]
    }, 1000);
```

However, everytime I try to search, I get "No results", even though the console logs no errors and the function is being called fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found a solution. Even though it's not specified at all in the docs, the directive expects a response like:

```
{"data": [Array of objects]}
```

Therefore, it works if I do it like:

```
$scope.search= function (userInputString, timeoutPromise) {
return $timeout(function () {
    return {"data": [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }, { "id": "3" }]};
}, 1000);
```

Hope it will help others.

Comment: Hi, if I want to preselect using remote-api-handler and initial-value, I am not able to do it. can you give one example of it. like we do some preselected value in edit records

Comment: @LorDisturbia: Thank you so much for the answer..Kindly link ur answer. in this question. I can provide bounty for you dude. cheers 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970571/angucomplete-alt-getting-no-results-found-before-the-server-response-is-obta/44315537#44315537