# Angucomplete Alt : Getting "No Results Found" before the server response is obtained

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to initiate a request after 3 characters but once 3 characters are typed I am getting the No records found error and after that I can find the service call get completed but nothing is shown in auto complete(only the error message under the autocomplete dropdown).What am I missing here?

HTML code:

```
       <angucomplete-alt id="angu_{{$index}}"
                                      placeholder="Search people"
                                      remote-api-handler="search"
                                      remote-url-data-field="results"
                                      title-field="fullName"
                                      minlength="3"
                                      input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                                      selected-object="selected"
                                      selected-object-data="$index"
                                      clear-selected="true"/>
```

Api remote handler

```
  $scope.search = function(str, timeoutPromise) {
   return $timeout(function () {
    $scope.input = {};
     $scope.input.userId = "";
     $scope.input.name = str;
     $scope.input.system = "";
     $scope.input.officeNumber = "";
     $scope.input.department= "";
     //  server call and get the response to $scope.organisationNames 
        var promise = genericAPIService.doApiCall(url, appConstant.POST,  
    JSON.stringify($scope.input));
            promise.then(
              function(payload) { 
                  console.log(payload);
                 $scope.organisationNames = payload.data.result.data.List;
                 $scope.results = [];
                 $scope.organisationNames.forEach(function(organisation) {
                        if ((organisation.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0)) {
                            $scope.results.push(organisation);
                        }
                    });
                 return scope.results;
              },
              function(errorPayload) {
                  $log.error('failure loading role json', errorPayload);
              }).finally(function(){ 
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });  
}
},5000);
};
```

Tried another version of the same:

```
 <angucomplete-alt id="angu_{{$index}}" 
                   placeholder="Search people" 
                   selected-object="selectedBusiness" 
                   selected-object-data="$index"  
                   clear-selected="true" 
                   input-class="form-control 
                   form-control-small" 
                   remote-api-handler="searchAPI" 
                   remote-url-data-field="responseData.data" 
                   title-field="fullName" minlength="3" />

   $scope.searchAPI = function (userInputString, timeoutPromise) {
   $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput = {};
   return $timeout(function () {
         $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput.userId = "";
         $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput.name = userInputString;
         $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput.system = "";
         $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput.officeNumber = "";
         $scope.approversAndEndorsersInput.department= "";
         return $http.post(appConstant.selfDomainName+appConstant.getApproversAndEndorsersList, JSON.stringify($scope.approversAndEndorsersInput), {timeout: timeoutPromise});


   }, 1000);
```

}

Comment: what REST endpoint are you hitting with `genericAPIService`

Comment: When the `errorPayload` handler fails to re-throw the error, the next `.then` block in the chain executes. It is important to re-throw  errors in order to skip subsequent `.then` blocks.

Comment: @georgeawg: it didnt go the error handler at all. Angu complete directive getting executed before the service call gets over.... Since no records found... That is wat i guess...

Comment: @bowofola: endpoint is giving the data.. After hitting the url.. Or it should be given in someother way?

Comment: well its hard to recreate the problem you're seeing. what is `angucomplete-alt`? a 3rd party library or a directive you created?

Comment: @bowofola: https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt  in github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.PFB the link which helped in solving it.

[Angucomplete-alt: Remote-API-handler not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251694/angucomplete-alt-remote-api-handler-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Did you see the plunk from the answer below, this and how to configure the angucomplete-alt directive was described there, and the methods were copied from your question, with only the api call changed

Answer (score 4):

#### First Example

In your first example you never return the `promise`

```
var promise = genericAPIService.doApiCall(url, appConstant.POST, ...
```

So the $timeout is never resolved with the response from the API
Return the `promise` at the end of the $timeout callback

#### Second Example

It looks like that you are not settings correctly the `remote-url-data-field`

Here's a plunker that I came with using your second example http://plnkr.co/edit/QsJFWh?p=preview and it works correctly, I have slightly altered the `searchAPI` method to show the last http response

When I misconfigured the `remote-url-data-field`, the response was made but the angucomplete read "No results found"

See the notes on the plunk, and try to configure it the way it works for you
If you can't bind the correct property, provide a response sample from your api, and we can come up with a solution

#### Using $timeout

The reason you are using `$timeout` to add a delay is not obvious, you do it in both examples. The only thing this does is to add an artificial delay of the given amount of time. If the reason is to add some debounce/delay to the input field triggering an API request, that won't cut it.

There is a `pause` property that can be configured with a delay in milliseconds that will ensure that the api will be called after this amount of time when the user has stopped typing.
You can see it on the plunker demo, the default value is 500
Since your custom service and $http (from the 2nd example) both return promises, you can directly return their result

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in your code, and in the documentation, I think the problem is that you're immediately returning a Promise from `$timeout` in your `searchAPI` function, which resolves itself as soon as the timeout is reached. This is why you'll see the "No Records Found" returned, and THEN your API is called. Instead, return your `$http` promise object directly. i.e.:

```
$scope.searchAPI = function(userInputString, timeoutPromise)
{
    // do some other stuff, stringify data, build url_endpoint
    return $http.post(url_endpoint, json_data, {timeout: timeoutPromise});
}
```

The `$http` promise will only resolve after your API has been consumed.